# Can I host images uploaded by user on HostGator?

Tags: amazon-s3, hosting, web-hosting, cloudinary

I have a website where users have the option to upload their profile images. Currently, I'm using Cloudinary to host those images. My client has asked me if I can host those images on HostGator since they already have a paid shared hosting account there. My question is

1. Can I even do that? I tried that on Heroku and they warn you that images etc stored on their server will be deleted in 24 hours when their dynos restart, and they recommend Amazon S3.
2. If yes, then I will definitely need some kind of API to work with since all this is handled by my server and there must be a way to upload and delete images programmatically.  It would be great if you could point me towards particular resources.
3. If no, then what are the industry standards for my particular use case?

Comment: If all the images are in Cloudinary, there is no preventing you to get all your assets to any platform you wish to use.

Comment: But that's my issue, the client wants me to host those images on Hostgator. I already had a working model with cloudinary, but he wants me to host those on his shared server on Hostgator.